# MongoDB delete documents not containing custom words

Tags: pandas, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have a news article scraper that pulls articles based on certain content. On occasions, the crawlers pull back articles irrelevant to what they're supposed to.

I want to delete documents that **DO NOT** contain the relevant keywords. I ran the below code in pandas and was successful in deleting the unwanted documents:

```
relevant_words = ['Bitcoin', 'bitcoin', 'Ethereum', 'ethereum', 'Tether', 'tether', 'Cardano', 'cardano', 'XRP', 'xrp']
articles['content'] = articles['content'][articles['content'].str.contains('|'.join(relevant_words))].str.lower()
articles.dropna(subset=['content'], inplace=True)
```

My DB structure is as follows:

```
_id:
title:
url:
description:
author:
publishedAt:
content:
source_id:
urlToImage:
summarization:
```

The `content` field can contain anyone from one sentence to several paragraphs. I'm thinking a python script that iterates over the `content` field looking for documents without the relevant words and deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

Filter into a new dataframe.
You were on the right track except you have to go in the following order;

join and convert to lower case:

```
'|'.join(relevant_words).lower()
```

Filter

```
m= articles['content'].str.contains('|'.join(relevant_words).lower())
```

Mask the filter

```
articles[m]
```

Combined code

```
new_articles=articles[articles['content'].str.contains('|'.join(relevant_words).lower())]
```